# Is it correct to say "... away from X a few Y"?

Tags: phrase-usage

I ask because I found very few [hits](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=%22%20away%20from%20me%20a%20few%22&oq=%22%20away%20from%20me%20a%20few%22&gs_l=serp.3..0i8i7i30k1l6j0i8i30k1l2j0i8i7i30k1.4508.4600.0.4758.2.2.0.0.0.0.103.185.1j1.2.0....0...1.1.64.serp..0.2.184.rWUP21E6NGw) on Google.

Example sentence:

> Our knees almost touched, so I wriggled myself away from her a few
>   centimeters.

Comment: Ŝajnas, ke ‘wriggle’ estas miselekto por ‘wiggle’. Cetere, en Merko, en la ĉiutaga lingvaĵo, ni ne diras na ‘centimeters’, sed ‘inches’. Do, mi dirus, “Our knees almost touched, so I wiggled myself away from her a few inches.”

Comment: @MikeJones, is there some reason you keep commenting in Esperanto?  I mean, I like Esperanto myself, but this is *English* Language Learners.SE.

Comment: @stangdon: it's my way of throwing up a red flag on the notion that to ask a question about English you have to already know English. This ought to be an Esperanto-hosted site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question. Syntactically this is correct! I would however word it:

```
Our knees almost touched, so I wriggled a few centimeters away from her.
```

That would sound more natural in my opinion.

Comment: So "myself" is superfluous here.